# Import a Json file to Firebase Remotely

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

is it possible to import a json file remotely to Firebase?

I'm currently running a java program, which generates the file I want to insert into my database, and then I have to manually enter it in the firebase.

Is there any way to do this automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this by using CURL ([Writing data with PUT](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data)).
You can also update the data with your JSON you got already exported earlier.  In case you got all data under one node it will be much faster.

Comment: Sorry to ask but I've never worked with REST. Is it possible to integrate this into the java program?

Comment: @L.Maltez tbh i ve never did that either, but according to this you can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682742/how-to-send-curl-in-android-to-rest-service. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might still need that..

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @FILE.json FIREBASE_ADDRESS
```